# ScopedTypeVariables doesn't bring type variables into scope

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-variables

Here's a simple function to return the alignment of a pointer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Foreign.Ptr (Ptr)
import Foreign.Storable (Storable, alignment)

main = return ()

ptrAlign1 :: (Storable a) => Ptr a -> Int
ptrAlign1 _ = alignment (undefined :: a)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Could not deduce (Storable a0) arising from a use of `alignment'
from the context (Storable a)
  bound by the type signature for
             ptrAlign1 :: Storable a => Ptr a -> Int
  at prog.hs:8:14-41
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
```

If I rewrite `ptrAlign` in a more messy faction like so:

```
ptrAlign2 :: (Storable a) => Ptr a -> Int
ptrAlign2 = ptrAlign3 undefined where
  ptrAlign3 :: (Storable a) => a -> Ptr a -> Int
  ptrAlign3 x _ = alignment x
```

It works fine (of course this version doesn't even need `ScopedTypeVariables`).

But I'm still curious about why the first version is throwing an error, and what can be done to resolve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even with `ScopedTypeVariables` turned on, type variables are not put in scope unless you explicitly quantify them, i.e.

```
ptrAlign1 :: forall a. (Storable a) => Ptr a -> Int
ptrAlign1 _ = alignment (undefined :: a)
```

Comment: what's the rationale behind this?

Comment: @ErikAllik: [The manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables) doesn't say, but I expect it's so that existing code doesn't have its behavior changed simply by turning on `ScopedTypeVariables`.